# Reporting error to microsoft

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an error on an SSIS package. I tried to report it to Microsoft, but it seems there is no support at the page where i logged my ticket (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2794452/error-when-openeing-or-executing-package)

Where am I supposed to log bug with MSSSIS?

Here is a link to a screen dump of the bug:https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ykgso5xuuw7vg4/SSIS%20package%20execution%20Visual%20Studio%20error.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Connect is not support. Is feedback.

If you need support, open a support case, via http://support.microsoft.com  Note that support is not free.